# How to wind up a stack of View Controller while deeplinking using branch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, branch.io

I was going through [this tutorial on branch](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/easy_deep_linking/ios/) to use it for deep-linking. My Intention is to load a stack of ViewControllers, say A, B over A, C over B, D over C, such that on being done with  a ViewController, the one below it is accessible. The example presents a single view controller to be deep-linked.

The overall intention of my deep-link is to have a fallback ViewController when the deep linked one is to be exited.
What is the best practice of stacking ViewControllers if I intend to following this tutorial, and make such a recoverable stack of ViewControllers?

Comment: UINavigationController provides a property called viewControllers.  This is an array of view controllers.  The first one is the root, the last one is on top.  Alternatively, do several pushes with animation=NO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UINavigationController` that is associated with you view controllers, and `pushViewController` to push new view controllers on the stack.